# How to use Maven project without artifactory or setting.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, artifactory

I am working on a project where we are using JFrog artifactory in Settings.xml something like this

[image]

Now, I have a requirement that we want to use maven project without settings.xml (By bypassing artifactory). As far as I know when we build project, by default it loads dependencies or libraries from Central Maven Repository or any public repository. As currently, I don't know how to skip settings.xml so I tried using with following settings.xml but it didn't work and gave me error "Could not resolve dependencies for project MyProject.core:bundle:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.adobe.aem:uber-jar:jar:apis:6.3.2.2 in com.springsource.repository.bundles.external".

[image]

Please guide me how can I skip artifactory or avoid from using settings.xml ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a proxy and can reach the outside world, you can remove your `settings.xml`, if you were previously only using it for Artifactory. This will fallback to using Maven Central as your default repository.

Of course, as I said earlier, you will need to be able to access the Internet without having to go through a proxy.

Comment: I have even tried by removing Settings.xml but it is not working and giving me following error "Failed to execute goal on project MyProject.core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.MyProject:MyProjet.core:bundle:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.adobe.aem:uber-jar:jar:apis:6.3.2.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced"

Comment: Do I need to remove Setting.xml from any other settings from eclipse ?

Comment: The error message is right: The jar that you are trying to use is _not_ in MavenCentral. So without `settings.xml`, you cannot use `uber-jar`.

Comment: The whole point of using an artifact repository manager like Artifactory is that you can define multiple repositories that need to access the outside world and keep a cache of the requested dependencies. In your case, it seem that your group repository is serving you serveral proxy and hosted repositories from where you're getting your dependencies. Maven Central doesn't contain all the Java artifacts in the world. Many projects host things elsewhere. For example, Adobe.

Comment: So I need to add dependency in pom for such libraries which are not in Maven Central Repository ?

Comment: No, you need to use a `settings.xml`. Without a `settings.xml` it cannot work. Unless, of course, you define the repositories in the POM, which is not really recommended.